# Send SOAP message body to endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The endpoint is OAuth protected and requires a SOAP message body in POST request in order to process the request successfully. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a mediation sequence [1] to get an Access token for the backend.

To support SOAP backends, create a SOAP API in API Manager. [2]

[1] https://medium.com/@menakajayawardena/wso2-how-to-using-oauth2-protected-back-ends-with-api-manager-5d7e234c61c

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Create+and+Publish+a+SOAP+API

Comment: I have done the same thing as you have suggested, the problem here is post backend gets authenticated via oauth2 using (as per the link[1]), but it post to the endpoint Content-Type remains as "application/json", resulting in empty "SOAPAction". I tried changing the Content-Type / messageType in the sequence mediation which is causing backend OAuth call to fail. Can you please advise on how to ensure that post the call for backend oauth is completed, Content-Type can be set to "text/xml" that might help out.

Comment: Could you please try adding this after the <filter>...</filter> section?

<header value="text/xml" name="Content-Type" scope="transport"/>

Comment: Tried this but the endpoint is receiving the message body as json format instead of soap as during mediation where messageType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded is set is converting the message body to format {"binary":"******" }.